# How to create "HTML Templates" in Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to develop an extension, which has repetitive layouts in different pages. These might include JS sources, CSS links, etc, and I don't want to need to modify every page for each small change. How can I avoid this and use a "templating system"? In PHP I can just `include` header/footer files, what's the equivalent in a Chrome extension environment? Can't say what I've already tried as I'm completely lost on this, I found no good results on Google (or maybe I'm not sure what to search).

Comment: You could write your template as an HTML page with a `div` element that should contain specific content, and then use AJAX calls to replace the content of that `div` with the content of other pages.

Comment: Please clarify whether you're doing this with the cooperation of the site or not (i.e., whether your extension is potentially hostile to the site owner), and whether you already know the content of the pages that your extension will be modifying (e.g., all on *.example.com, or anywhere on the web). These answers will help us understand your use case better.

Comment: @sowbug what site? I'm developing an extension and I need footer/header file equivalents in my pages. So an equivalent to including them in JS or chrome's API would be...?

 Metoule I'm considering this, but I was hoping there's a smarter way